# Which GridGain version is compatible with Apache Ignite 2.11.0

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We use Apache Ignite 2.11.0 and plan to migrate to GridGain.

Which version is compatible and how to migrate to GridGain Community?

We use .NET Core. Do we change the program code or migrate without change?

Answer (score 1):

GridGain is based on Apache Ignite, but they are not 100% compatible, and there is no 1-to-1 version mapping.

Having said that:

- In most cases the migration is smooth - just change the package reference.
- Latest available GridGain version is recommended.